# windows 10 home keep going into sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have a problem with my Toshiba satellite laptop, windows 10 home:
It is connected to 2 monitors, I use the best performance power settings, with all configuration to 'Power Sleep Never', but if I stop using the PC, or if I stop playing any video, in 2 minutes it goes in sleep.

I cannot find a way to disable this behaviors. It has not vendor software installed.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. A [Windows update changed sleep settings, which may now be hidden](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-keeps-going-into-sleep-after-1-minute/787e8cea-32ce-4ea0-a281-13c32a75352d?auth=1). If the settings below are hidden, it also could be due to a Group Policy setting... if you are using a PC provided by an employer, check with IT staf before attempting a change! However, it is possible [to change these settings on your own PC](https://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-sleep-option-missing-in-windows-power-menu/).

   - Press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type *buttons*.
   - Select *Change what the power buttons do*.
     [image: Choose hidden settings]
   - Select *Change settings that are currently unavailable*.
   - Now click on *Power Options* at top of dialog, and check all settings for sleep time.
2. If you have a screen saver enabled, that might have a short timeout set.

Comment: I do not see that option, and neither the other default power plans

Comment: @albanx: See the change above, showing how to use Regedit to make these settings visible. *N.B.* Do not change this for a corporate machine.

Comment: By doing the registry trick in the above link, seems working. thanks

Comment: actually it seems not working any more. The only reason I do not format it because it bothers me setup everything

Answer (score 3):

If you truly have tried all the power settings and they are correct and it is still going to sleep, I would recommend installing Caffeine: http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/

It will move the mouse automatically 1 pixel every minute so the machine does not go to sleep.